# Robot-Framework-Test-Automation selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I need help to use a syntax similar to `driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame()` in python 2.7. This syntax work fine in C#

Can anybody tell me how to get back to `parent frame` from `child frame`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get back to the parent from any child frame, but you can get from a child frame back to the main frame by calling the Selenium2Library keyword [Unselect frame](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Unselect%20Frame)

Comment: Thanks bryan oakley's. 

I thought it could be possible if we use driver. Switch_to. parent_frame()

As it works in visual studio and eclipse if we include selenium webdriver